# How to dispatch an action onClick in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I have created a cricket match score card application. Here I want to update score of a player. I have created two buttons for updating the score. One button for increasing the score & other for decreasing the score. I want to update score on button click.

Here is my code to button to update the score -

```
const Counter = props => (
  <div className="counter" >
    <button
      className="counter-action decrement"
      onClick={() => props.updatePlayerScore(props.index, -1)}>
      -
    </button>
    <div className="counter-score"> {props.score} </div>
    <button
      className="counter-action increment"
      onClick={() => props.updatePlayerScore(props.index, 1)}>
      +
    </button>
  </div>);

  Counter.propTypes = {
      updatePlayerScore: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      score: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

export default Counter;
```

My action file code is -

```
export const updatePlayerScore = (index, score)  => {
   return {
     type: PlayerActionTypes.UPDATE_PLAYER_SCORE,
     index,
     score
  };
};
```

My reducer file code is -

```
case PlayerActionTypes.UPDATE_PLAYER_SCORE:
      const updatePlayerList = state.map((player, index) => {
        if(index === action.index) {
          return {
            ...player,
            score: player.score + action.score,
            updated: `${day}/${month}/${year}`
          };
        }
        return player;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        players: updatePlayerList
      }
```

When I am clicking on increment button. It's throwing an error like state.map is not defined. I want to update the player score accordingly. I am new to redux. Please someone help me in that.

Comment: Please also show where `state` in your reducer comes from. The error indicates, that `state` has no property `map()` so it likely isn't an array that you can iterate through. I suspect it is an object as you are trying to spread it into the new state a little bit further down.

Comment: @trixn is right, also state shouldn't be a `[]`, state properties can take any form, `{}` or `[]` but your initial state should be an `{}`. also, inside a case `don't` define variables!

Comment: @sonkatamas Why shouldn't you declare a variable in a `case` if you immediately return it?

Comment: The reason is that the lexical declaration is visible in the entire switch block but it only gets initialized when it is assigned, which will only happen if the case where it is defined is reached. Also the return is not immediate we don't see the cases under it. There is one return statement before it returns `updatePlayerList`.

Comment: @sonkatamas As far as I can see the case ends with an unconditional return statement so it is impossible for the control flow to reach another case. Whenever this case is hit it will definitely return inside of that case. The return statement you mentioned is inside of the callback of `.map()`.

Comment: you are right, I did not notice that all happens inside the callback of `.map()`!

Answer (score 0):

May be your dispatching of redux actions are not correct. try to dispatch actions in this way and see if it helps

```
import {useDisptach} from 'react-redux'
import {updatePlayerScore} from '//your-action-file-path'

const Counter = (props) => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch()
 return (
  <div className="counter" >
    <button
      className="counter-action decrement"
      onClick={() => dispatch(updatePlayerScore(props.index, -1)) }>. //look here
      -
    </button>
    <div className="counter-score"> {props.score} </div>
    <button
      className="counter-action increment"
      onClick={() => dispatch(updatePlayerScore(props.index, 1))}> //look here
      +
    </button>
  </div>);
}

  Counter.propTypes = {
      updatePlayerScore: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      score: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

export default Counter;
```